# Symfony - Most secure way to authenticate using REST?

Tags: rest, session, authentication, angular5, symfony4

I'm trying to build a proof of concept using Angular 5 and Symfony 4. I need the backend to be decoupled from the frontend so that I can focus on using JS entirely for the frontend and to be able to escalate to apps and other types of clients.

For this reason I'm building a RESTful API on Symfony. I've managed to send credentials from the front to the back... and that's pretty much what I've managed to do because I don't know how to proceed next.

Symfony should take the login data, somehow call a service to validate, and respond properly to the frontend. What is the most secure way of doing this? I've read a lot about JWT and how it's unfitting for this use case, and apparently OAuth2 is good only for authorization and not authentication unless you use OpenId Connect. I've read that the simplest approach is to create a session ID + a CSRF token and store it in a cookie (I don't care if this breaks statelessness, being certain that the system is secure is more important). I think the latter can be done with a bundle transparently but I don't know how to do the former.

In fact I'm entirely lost. I don't know where to begin, I've been stuck for days and the task seems just too overwhelming. I was even suggested to use Laravel instead, but I don't even know where to get started and this is legit the first time I try to implement a REST API, so it's quite daunting.

What am I supposed to do here?

EDIT: Here are some of the reasons why I'm schewing JWT for authentication.

> Wanting to use JWT instead of OpenID Connect is like wanting to use a SAML assertion without the SAML protocol.[1](https://www.gluu.org/blog/jwt-not-authentication-protocol/)

(This one could lead me to use OpenID Connect as my solution)

> Stateless JWT tokens cannot be invalidated or updated, and will introduce either size issues or security issues depending on where you store them. Stateful JWT tokens are functionally the same as session cookies, but without the battle-tested and well-reviewed implementations or client support.[2](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/)
>
> Unfortunately, an attacker can abuse this. If a server is expecting a token signed with RSA, but actually receives a token signed with HMAC, it will think the public key is actually an HMAC secret key.[3](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/)
>
> This isn't just an implementation bug, this is the result of a failed standard that shouldn't be relied on for security. If you adhere to the standard, you must process and "understand" the header. You are explicitly forbidden, by the standard, to just disregard the header that an attacker provides.[4](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid)

The linked websites have more information as of why JWT is not secure.

Comment: I’d be interested to hear why you think JWT is not suitable, as a lot of people use JWT for exactly your use case.

Comment: Why wouldn't JWT be suitable for your use-case? But anyway: just plain old sessions are fine as well. Just use HTTP-only secure flagged cookies, whatever you do. If it is only for making an API, just Lumen (stripped version of Laravel) specific for APIs https://lumen.laravel.com/

Comment: @BlueM Hi, I have edited my post explaining some reasons!

Comment: @Jørgen I will give that one a look, I definitely need just an API! I also edited my post stating the reasons why JWT is not suitable for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am implementing a similar task, only on the frontend Vue.js. On the backend I use Symphony 4 + [API Platform](https://api-platform.com/). At the moment, I implement secure access to the API through [JWT Authentication](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt), this method is recommended.

**Links for your topic:**

- https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle
- https://gist.github.com/lologhi/7b6e475a2c03df48bcdd
- https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle

*If you want fast setup, then use [FOSUserBundle Integration](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/fosuser-bundle), but API Platform not recomendated his method.*

**Or use this method at Symfony4:** -

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/api_key_authentication.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Comment: Hi and thanks for linking those. I've seen those links before, but sadly none of them answers my question about how to use cookies and sessions for RESTful APIs. I can make a guard, but nowhere it is explained how cookies come into play, or how to invoke them programatically because I have to code the /login route all by myself.